# Facebook Sharing Debugger returns "The document returned no data."

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, web-scraping

I have a website at https://expr4j.pratanumandal.tk/.

I am trying to scrape my website through Facebook Sharing Debugger for thumbnail previews.

However, whenever I attempt to fetch a new scrape of my website, it is reporting that no Open Graph tags were found.

When clicking into "See exactly what our scraper sees for your URL", the scraper returns:

```
The document returned no data
```

I have checked with Facebook user agent in both cURL and Chrome, and in both cases I am getting the proper response.

Can you please help me to get my page thumbnail previews on Facebook.

Comment: do you block crawlers on your server? sounds like a server thing to me.

Comment: @luschn I have not actively configured any crawlers to be blocked. In fact, Google can crawl my site easily. I am using Cloudflare SSL, and even there I have added Firewall rule to allow AS Number for Facebook. I am able to cURL to my page and also from Chrome using Facebook user agent.

Comment: @luschn Suddenly, I was able to scrape on Facebook. But this time, I faced a different issue. This time I got the following error: Provided og:image, https://expr4j.pratanumandal.tk/img/expr4j.png could not be downloaded. This can happen due to several different reasons such as your server using unsupported content-encoding. The crawler accepts deflate and gzip content encodings.